# Is it possible to get a list of available instance types in a specific availability zone for AWS RDS?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, cloud, rds

I`m trying to modify RDS DB Instance launched in vpc by AWS API using [ModifyDBInstance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_ModifyDBInstance.html) action. I`m not change instance type (instance launched with db.m1.small type and not canged), but I`m reciving message:

> AWS Error. Request ModifyDBInstance failed. Cannot modify the instance class because there are no instances of the requested class available in the current instance's availability zone. Please try your request again at a later time. (RequestID: xxx).

According to AWS docs

> To determine the instance classes that are available for a particular DB engine, use the DescribeOrderableDBInstanceOptions action. Note that not all instance classes are available in all regions for all DB engines.

So I have two quastions:

1. Is it possible to get by API only Instance types available in specific AZ? In `DescribeOrderableDBInstanceOptions` actions responce I have many instance types, which not available. I`m also checked responce of `DescribeReservedDBInstancesOfferings` action, and it`s doesn`t fit.
2. Why it possible to launch DBInstance with some instance type, but have troubles on trying to modify it DBInstance without changing instance type?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of the return values listed in this [AWS RDS CLI call](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-orderable-db-instance-options.html) is AvailabilityZones

```
AvailabilityZones -> (list)
A list of Availability Zones for the orderable DB instance.
(structure)
Contains Availability Zone information.
This data type is used as an element in the following data type:
OrderableDBInstanceOption
Name -> (string)
The name of the availability zone.
```

Generally the CLI allows your to filter but it is not support for rds for some reason or another.

```
--filters (list)

This parameter is not currently supported.
```

The API returns the object [OrderableDBInstanceOption](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_OrderableDBInstanceOption.html) which also has the AZ listed.

To answer #2 is that AWS does have capacity issues from time to time, like any other cloud or service provider, they are generally better at handling it than others. What AZ are you trying to use and size of instance? If you continue to have issues I would open a support ticket with AWS.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to select any one of the Rds instance you have in your infrastructure and click on Modify and there will be one option like dbInstanceTypes it is like drop down where you can find available instance types available in the particular region.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you availability for given instance type per AZ in a region

*aws rds describe-orderable-db-instance-options --engine MySQL --engine-version 8.0.27 --db-instance-class db.m6g.large --output text --region eu-central-1*

```
ORDERABLEDBINSTANCEOPTIONS  db.m6g.large    mysql   8.0.27  general-public-license          65536           5   True    False   True    gp2 False   True    False   True    False   True    True    True    True    True
AVAILABILITYZONES   eu-central-1a
AVAILABILITYZONES   eu-central-1b
AVAILABILITYZONES   eu-central-1c
SUPPORTEDNETWORKTYPES   DUAL
SUPPORTEDNETWORKTYPES   IPV4
```

You can filter by other instance parameters, like storage type too:

*aws rds describe-orderable-db-instance-options --engine MySQL --engine-version 8.0.27 --db-instance-class db.m6g.large --output text --region eu-central-1 --query "*[?StorageType=='gp2']"*